Query to calculate SUM of below top level Childs calculated amount
I have a Table TestPoolCalc, I need to show current node amount + sum of below top level Childs calculated amount. Please see the expected output
Table Script and Data
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc](
    [PoolID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentPoolID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Amount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1
', N'ROOT', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.1
', N'Pool 1
', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.1.1
', N'Pool 1.1
', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.1.1.1
', N'Pool 1.1.1
', CAST(-12500.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.1.1.2
', N'Pool 1.1.1
', CAST(-12500.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.1.2
', N'Pool 1.1
', CAST(-25000.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.2
', N'Pool 1
', CAST(25000.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 1.3', N'Pool 1
', CAST(-50000.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 2', N'ROOT', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 2.1', N'Pool 2', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 2.2', N'Pool 2', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'Pool 2.3', N'Pool 2', CAST(75000.00 AS Numeric(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_TestPoolCalc] ([PoolID], [ParentPoolID], [Amount]) VALUES (N'ROOT', NULL, NULL)
GO

Way I tried
  WITH p AS (SELECT            
   a.ParentPoolID, a.PoolID 
   , CAST(a.PoolID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS path    
   , len(CAST(a.PoolID AS VARCHAR(MAX))) lpath    
   , a.Amount    
   
  FROM _TestPoolCalc a    
  WHERE a.ParentPoolID = 'Root'    
        UNION ALL    
  SELECT    
   pp.ParentPoolID, pp.PoolID   
   , p_2.path + '>' + pp.PoolID AS path    
   , len(p_2.path + '>' + pp.PoolID) lpath    
   , pp.Amount   
    
  FROM _TestPoolCalc pp     
     
  JOIN p AS p_2 ON pp.ParentPoolID = p_2.PoolID 
  )    
SELECT PoolID,ParentPoolID, path    
,Amount
,isnull((select sum(isnull(p1.Amount,0.0)) from p p1 where left(p1.path,p.lpath) = p.path and p.poolid <> p1.PoolId ),0) CalculatedAmount     
FROM  p
order by path

Expected output



#
PoolID (A)
Amount (B)
Calculated Amount (C)




1
Pool 1
NULL
-75000 B1+C2+C7+C8


2
Pool 1.1
NULL
-50000 B2+C3+C6


3
Pool 1.1.1
NULL
-25000 B3+C4+C5


4
Pool 1.1.1.1
-12500.00
-12500 B4


5
Pool 1.1.1.2
-12500.00
-12500 B5


6
Pool 1.1.2
-25000.00
-25000 B6


7
Pool 1.2
25000.00
25000 B7


8
Pool 1.3
-50000.00
-50000 B8


9
Pool 2
NULL
75000 B9+C10+C11+C12


10
Pool 2.1
NULL
0 B10


11
Pool 2.2
NULL
0 B11


12
Pool 2.3
75000
75000 B12




Using your test data:
WITH p AS (
    SELECT  poolid AS main, t.Amount, t.PoolID AS parent
    FROM    _TestPoolCalc t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  p.main, tc.amount, tc.poolid
    FROM    p
    INNER JOIN _TestPoolCalc tc
        ON  tc.ParentPoolID = p.parent
  )    
SELECT  Main, ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0) AS total
FROM    p
GROUP BY Main

For each node, i gather it and all the children under it. By keeping the PoolID as main, it becomes very easy to gather the final result, although, this code does traverse levels multiple times which can have some performance implications.
Output:



Main
Total




Pool 1
-75000


Pool 1.1
-50000


Pool 1.1.1
-25000


Pool 1.1.1.1
-12500


Pool 1.1.1.2
-12500


Pool 1.1.2
-25000


Pool 1.2
25000


Pool 1.3
-50000


Pool 2
75000


Pool 2.1
0


Pool 2.2
0


Pool 2.3
75000


ROOT
0



You can always remove the ROOT if you're not interested in it.
